# When row contains a value, average other cells in same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, average, offset

Let's say I have Row 21 titled "Stadium".  Cells in this row contain any integer between `1` and `24`.  I need to create another cell with some formula that will do the following:

Find all cells in Row 21 that contain the value (integer) "6".  Then, it needs to average the sum of all of the cells that are a given number of cells (such as nineteen) above the cells containing `6`.  For example:

[The Spreadsheet I'm Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEFjc.png)
[image: The Spreadsheet I'm Using]

**Since Row 21 (Stadium) contains the value `6` twice, I need the highlighted cell (which I chose randomly) to output the average of cells B2 and E2 (which are nineteen cells above).**  So whatever formula I put in should output `11.5` which is the average number of `Boost` items obtained for every Stadium #6 event.  If I wanted to find the average number of `Glide` items obtained for every Stadium #3, for example, the formula would output `13` since only one Stadium #3 is recorded.

I would change the values in the formula manually depending on what stadium number I'm looking for (i.e. `6` or `3`) or what item I am looking for (i.e `Boost` or `Glide`).

The reason that the formula needs to be set up this way is because data will be continually entered into this spreadsheet and that data entry will never be finished.

I figure that this might involve the OFFSET and AVERAGE functions but I have no idea what else this would involve.  This is where I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following solution:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(B21:G21=6,INDIRECT("B"&MATCH("Boost",A:A,0)&":G"&MATCH("Boost",A:A,0)),""))
```

Inputted as an array formula using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. Explaining the logic first in the indirect; it finds the row matching column A to the item you want to report on (ie Boost or Glide). With the row it creates a range in the indirect referencing the row you want values for. It then generates an array with only the values for the columns of the stadium (6 in this case) by comparing the array of the same dimension formed from the Stadium row to your target stadium. Lastly it takes the average of the resulting array to output the expected answer. Regards,